# FXCollections.observableArrayList nullpointer

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, setter

Hopefully someone can help me with this problem.
I try to make a Junit test for a class. 
But somehow I always recieve nullpointer when I try to create  a object to test.

There is something wrong with my setter in that class.

```
private ReservatieSpecificatie geselecteerdeResSpec;
private long id;
private GebruikerRepository gebruikerRepository;
DBCommunicatie databank = new DBCommunicatie();
private SimpleListProperty reservaties = new SimpleListProperty();
private SimpleObjectProperty ophaalMoment = new SimpleObjectProperty();
private SimpleObjectProperty indienMoment = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
private SimpleStringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

public Reservatie(Calendar ophaalMoment, Calendar indienMoment, List<ReservatieSpecificatie> reservaties, String email) {
    gebruikerRepository = new GebruikerRepository(databank);
    setOphaalMoment(ophaalMoment);
    setIndienMoment(indienMoment);
    setReservaties(reservaties);
    setEmail(email);

}

   public void setReservaties(List<ReservatieSpecificatie> reservaties) {
            this.reservaties.set(FXCollections.observableArrayList(reservaties));
        }
```

I recieve this track of errors:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:343)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.addAll(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:99)
    at javafx.collections.FXCollections.observableArrayList(FXCollections.java:341)
    at domein.Reservatie.setReservaties(Reservatie.java:133)
    at domein.Reservatie.<init>(Reservatie.java:65)
    at domein.ReservatieTest.setUp(ReservatieTest.java:45)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: `reservaties` is `null`. Maybe you should post the `setUp` method, if you cannot find out why.

Comment: To further clarify fabian's point:  The List object being passed to the constructor is null.  You may want to put `Objects.requireNonNull(reservaties);` at the start of your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) for `AbstractCollection.addAll()`, you can see that `NullPointerException` is thrown when "the specified collection contains a null element and this collection does not permit null elements, or if the specified collection is null."  So either the `reservaties` argument itself is null or, more likely, it contains a null element.

Comment: Since [`FXCollection.observableArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-java.util.Collection-) creates a list that permits `null` elements, the "less likely" thing happens.